# Pull all branches from the remote on another PC

Tags: git, svn, github

I created a repo on one computer, then created some branches there, and pushed the changes. Right now I have the following branches:

- master
- develop
- hotfix

Then I began using another computer, so I cloned the repo, and wanted to checkout to different branch. But it gave me an error that it doesn't exist.

`git checkout develop` gives me that error

I tried fetching the branch, so I used:

`git fetch origin develop`, but it throws 'fatal couldn't find remote ref develop, unexpected end of command stream'

Is there a way to "download" all these branches on that different PC?

Thanks!

Comment: what error message did you get when you executed 'git checkout develop'?

Comment: try `git branch -r`.  Also specify which repo you cloned.

Answer (score 0):

If all branches are really on remote, then you can just call

```
git fetch origin
```

to checkout specific branch, if it doesn't exist locally yet you need

```
git checkout -b name origin/name
```

By the way, make sure you have set remotes correctly

```
git remote -v
```